# In relativity why does matter bend spacetime in a downward direction

Tags: gravity, general-relativity, space-time

A major flaw , I think it is in relativity.

Comment: When asking a question, it is best to include research that you have done, the reasoning that has led you to ask this question, and clarification for the nature of your question. Try expanding upon your question in the title by adding more details in the body of the question!

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't. If you're talking about pictures like this:

[image]

those are only meant to show the shape of a slice of spacetime. Turning them sideways or upside down changes nothing. All that matters is that the circumference is less than $π$ times the diameter.

I don't know why they are almost always shown pointing down. I suspect that many people are confused by the "rubber sheet analogy" or by the gravity wells at science museums into thinking that turning them upside down would turn gravity into antigravity. It wouldn't. To get antigravity you'd need a shape whose circumference is *more* than $π$ times its diameter, which would look very different.